# I'm not quite sure I understand my book's reasoning for the answer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have the following homework problem:

Does there exist a graph, $G$, with 28 edges and 12 vertices, each of degree 3 or 4?

First, my solution.

$$
\sum deg(v_i) = 2 \cdot |E| \\
|E| = 28 \Rightarrow 2 \cdot |E| = 2 \cdot 28 = 56 \\
\forall v_i \in V, deg(v_i) = 4 \\
\text{thus} \sum deg(v_i) = 4 \cdot 12 = 48 \neq 56 \\
\therefore \text{no such graph exists} \square
$$

Now, the book's:
$$
\text{Suppose G has } a\, \text{vertices of degree 3 and } b\, \text{vertices of degree 4.} \\
\text{Then, } \sum deg\,v_i = 3a + 4b = 56 = 2\cdot |E| \, \text{and}\, a+b = 12. \\
\text{These equations imply}\, a < 0, \text{which cannot be.  No such G exists.}
$$

I'm not sure I see why the equations imply that $a < 0$.  Is it essentially what I have or have I missed the mark?

Thanks for the help,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the book solution, you have two equations: $3a+4b = 56$ and $a+b =12$, subtracting 4 multiples of the second from the first yields $-a = 8$, so $a<0$, which cannot be.

Your proof cannot assume all degrees are 4, some could be 3, so correct it to an inequality:
$$\sum \deg v_i \leq 4 \cdot 12 = 48 < 56$$
which yields the desired contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much for making this painfully clear.  I tried subtracting 3 multiples of the second equation $a+b=12$.  I apparently didn't do something correctly because I was finding that a > 0.  Also, I didn't realize that my proof was not sound.  Thank you for the clarification on that.  That inequality is great.

Answer (score 0):

$$3a+4b=56\\
a+b=12\implies b=12-a\\
\implies 3a+48-4a=56\\
\implies -a=8\\
\implies a=-8<0$$